# Handling attachments with REST WS

Tags: java, rest

Friends,

Is it possible to send attachments (binary content) to a RESTful WS, as we do to SOAP based WS ? How do we handle it in the REST WS ? I intend to work with Java APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP is quite capable of sending and receiving binary media types.  For a pure binary stream of bytes, just POST or PUT a body of bytes using the media type `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: so you could just have a public void moo(byte[] foo) and the MediaType to MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE?

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood  The specific syntax depends on the framework being used.

Comment: It will be xml + binary separated by boundaries (basically, multipart/related content type). would your suggestion still work ??

Comment: @Seeker Yes.  Http is completely capable of doing that.  Whether your HTTP client/server framework make it easy to do is a different issue.